# AWS Codecommit Markdown embedded pictures images

Tags: amazon-web-services, markdown, aws-codecommit

We are using AWS Codecommit for our projects documentation in Markdown.

I would like to know how it is possible to create a markdown link that allows to display embedded images (to be visualized while in CodeCommit).

The images are also in Codecommit. Do we need to use S3 and point there? I wanted to keep the images private to our project.

TIA

Solution:

It seems to work with SVG files.

Comment: Markdown has native support for images. What about that is not working? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @Waylan Hi, i was looking for a way to markdown reference images in the same Codecommit repository, and be able to see it when browsing in CodeCommit. We store everything in AWS so we would use it as a wiki.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Same question as Waylan; is there an issue with native Markdown support in CodeCommit.

At this time, CodeCommit does not support the ability to reference images in markdown that are stored within the same CodeCommit repository. I will pass this feature request along to the team to consider in their development roadmap.

Comment: As discussed in [this AWS forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=273712), this feature is not yet available.

Comment: What did happen to  'I will pass this feature request along to the team to consider in their development roadmap'? 

1. where is this roadmap? 
2. did it get implemented? 
3. is there any other written document that this has been added to a development roadmap? 

Or is AWS playin its devrel marketing stunt game here?

Comment: Still not implemented